# "flatten" data based on match from two data frames in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames as follows

The first is a survey table which tells when a person's survey was taken

```
ID = c('1000021','1000021')
SurveyDate = c('2014-05-30','2013-05-01')
dfsurvey = data.frame(ID,SurveyDate)
> dfsurvey
              ID  SurveyDate
1        1000021  2014-05-30
2        1000021  2013-05-01
```

The second is a hobbies table which tells the person's hobbies recorded on that day. On different days, his hobbies could be different.

```
ID = c('1000021','1000021','1000021','1000021','1000021','1000021','1000021')
HobbyName = c('Running','Volleyball','Pingpong','Badminton','Swimming','Running','Pingpong')
SurveyDate = c('2014-05-30','2014-05-30','2014-05-30','2014-05-30','2014-05-30','2013-05-01','2013-05-01')
dfhobby = data.frame(ID,HobbyName,SurveyDate)
> dfhobby
   ID                                      HobbyName  SurveyDate
1        1000021                             Running  2014-05-30
2        1000021                          Volleyball  2014-05-30
3        1000021                            Pingpong  2014-05-30
4        1000021                           Badminton  2014-05-30
5        1000021                            Swimming  2014-05-30
6        1000021                             Running  2013-05-01
7        1000021                            Pingpong  2013-05-01
```

To the survey table which has only two rows, I would like to add the expanded list of hobbies, each hobby getting it's own column, what I would call "flattening". Something like this,

```
#expected final output - add columns to dfsurvey
> dfsurvey
ID     SurveyDate                        Hobby_Running     Hobby_Volleyball     Hobby_Pingpong    Hobby_Badminton Hobby_Swimming
1        1000021                                 1                    1                  1                  1              1 
2        1000021                                 1                    0                  1                  0              0
```

This is my code
I basically first construct the column names, and then use a nested for loop to mark 1 against the hobby. However, this is very very slow, around one second for one iteration of the nested for loop

```
#making columns and setting them to 0 as default
hobbyvalues = unique(dfhobby$HobbyName)
for(i in 1:length(hobbyvalues))
{
    print(i)
    dfsurvey[paste("Hobby_",hobbyvalues[i],sep="")] = 0
}

#flattening iterative
for(i in 1:nrow(dfsurvey))
{
    print(i)

    listofhobbies = dfhobby[which(dfhobby$ID == dfsurvey[i,"ID"] & dfhobby$SurveyDate == dfsurvey[i,"SurveyDate"]),"HobbyName"]

    if(length(listofhobbies) > 0)
    {
        for(l in 1:length(listofhobbies))
        {
            dfsurvey[i,paste("Hobby_",listofhobbies[l],sep="")] = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried the foreach package and doMC package and was able to write code in parallel. However, this is slow as well.

Is there a better way or library in R which can help me do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Based on your expected result, something like `reshape2::dcast(dfhobby, SurveyDate ~ HobbyName, length)` might do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> library(reshape2)
> dcast(dfhobby,ID*SurveyDate~HobbyName,fill=0,length)

       ID SurveyDate Badminton Pingpong Running Swimming Volleyball
1 1000021 2013-05-01         0        1       1        0          0
2 1000021 2014-05-30         1        1       1        1          1


> dcast(dfhobby,SurveyDate~HobbyName,fill=0,length)

  SurveyDate Badminton Pingpong Running Swimming Volleyball
1 2013-05-01         0        1       1        0          0
2 2014-05-30         1        1       1        1          1
```

Comment: thanks. It's working for sample data.
But with my data set, I get an error as follows
Using SurveyDate as value column: use value.var to override.

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7fff413441c0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .Call("split_indices", group, as.integer(n))
 2: split_indices(.group, .n)
 3: vaggregate(.value = value, .group = overall, .fun = fun.aggregate,     ..., .default = fill, .n = n)
 4: cast(data, formula, fun.aggregate, ..., subset = subset, fill = fill,     drop = drop, value.var = value.var)
 5: dcast(dfhobby,SurveyDate~HobbyName,fill=0,length)

Answer (score 1):

R packages `dplyr` and `tidyr` are here just to do this. They are very fast to work on large datasets also. For more info on this see data manipulation cheatsheet in [Rstudio page](http://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(ID,SurveyDate,HobbyName) %>% 
    mutate(Count = n()) %>% spread(HobbyName ,Count,fill=0)
```

Comment: I get this error below
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") :
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"